# Will "system()" call in Ruby wait until it finishes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby on rails. I want to call a system command to analyze an uploaded file in my Rails application. Something as follows:

```
after_save :analyse  #post processing call
def analyse
    command = "./c_executable " + Rails.root.to_s + "/output_csv_file"
    system(command)
    if FileTest.exists?(Rails.root.to_s + "/output_csv_file")
       parse_csv
    end
end
```

It runs fine on my local machine, but for some reason the function "parse_csv" won't get called on the server(dreamhost). However, I manually call the c_executable system command on the server and it outputs the csv file without a problem. Could anyone tell me what might be causing the problem here? I was thinking the system call takes some time to finish on the server. If that's the case, I'm wondering if there is a way to tell rails to wait until the system() call finishes execution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it generating any errors? Or can you see if the system(command) is returning true or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question now. After spending several days of testing and googling, it turns out that dreamhost doesn't allow these kind of non built-in system calls. I'll have to change my hosting service.

Answer (score 4):

The system call should block until the command inside is finished. It is possible that the file is not being created as you intended which might preclude that part of your app from running.

You might want to use a different way of constructing your path to be sure you're getting it right:

```
csv_path = File.expand_path('output_csv_file', Rails.root)

unless (system('./c_executable', csv_path))
  # Could't execute system command for some reason.
end

if (File.exists?(csv_path))
  # ...
end
```

When making `system` calls it's generally a good idea to specify the full path to the executable as your application `PATH` may be different from what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried your method. But again, everything works fine on the local machine but not on the server. Really confused.

Comment: You should check what `system` returns because it might indicate there was an error running your external program.

Comment: Hey tadman, thanks but how do I check the detailed returned information or errors? Can you be more specific please?

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that it's a permissions error. Do you know what user the web/app server is running as and see if it has the correct permissions to both read/execute the command and write the output file.

Comment: I checked the permission for the c executable is -rwxrwxr-x. Is it right?

Comment: That should be fine for the executable. What about the directory where the output file is being written to? Does the web/app server have permission to write there?

Comment: There is an old dreamhost post that says the directory needs to be 755 permissions to write to it http://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-79148.html

Comment: I checked the output csv_file is -rw-rw-r--. So I should create a directory with 755 permission and put my output file there right? Thank you! I'll try that and see if it works.

Comment: Hey r-dub, I tried what you suggest and it doesn't seem to work. I even tried a directory with permission 777 but still no luck. Weird. But thanks for your help anyway!